# How to write a cypher query which recursively traverses a graph in Neo4j to find all the nodes visited

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a graph in neo4j community edition running in a docker container in my local using below cypher.

```
create (a:Account{name:'account.a'}),
(b:Account{name:'account.b'}),
(c:Account{name:'account.c'}),
(d:Account{name:'account.d'}),
(e:Account{name:'account.e'}),
(f:Account{name:'account.f'}),
(x:Account{name:'account.x'}),
(y:Account{name:'account.y'}),
(cas:Calculation{name:'account.a:simple_interest'}),
(cac:Calculation{name:'account.a:compound_interest'}),
(cbs:Calculation{name:'account.b:simple_interest'}),
(cbc:Calculation{name:'account.b:compound_interest'}),
(cxs:Calculation{name:'account.x:simple_interest'}),
(cxc:Calculation{name:'account.x:compound_interest'}),
(a)-[:RESULTS_FROM]->(cas),
(a)-[:RESULTS_FROM]->(cac),
(b)-[:RESULTS_FROM]->(cbs),
(b)-[:RESULTS_FROM]->(cbc),
(x)-[:RESULTS_FROM]->(cxs),
(x)-[:RESULTS_FROM]->(cxc),
(cas)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(d),
(cas)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(e),
(cbs)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(c),
(cbc)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(y),
(cac)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(f),
(cac)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(d),
(cxs)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(d),
(cxc)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(d)
```

There are two kinds of nodes in the graph - **Account** and **Calculation**.
**Account** node has a "RESULTS_FROM" relation to **Calculation** node with the same name + interest type. A **Calculation** node has a "DEPENDS_ON" relation with 'n' number of other **Account** nodes.

Below is how the graph looks like.

[image]

I need to write a cypher which starts at an Account node and finds all it's dependencies in the entire graph. A dependency in this context is the Calculation node(s) it "RESULTS_FROM" and the Account nodes that those Calculation node(s) "DEPENDS_ON". It should do this recursively in all direction until it finds an Account node which doesn't have any "RESULTS_FROM" relation to any other Calculation nodes.

In the snapshot, if I start at "account.b", it will follow both "RESULTS_FROM" relation (via blue Calculation nodes) which then point to "account.y" and "account.c" via "DEPENDS_ON".

So the output should be - account.y and account.c

Similarly, the output for "account.x" should be "account.d". We stop when any Account doesn't "RESULT_FROM" any Calculation.

I tried different things like below but I am not sure what's the ideal way to do this.

```
MATCH (startNode:YourLabel {name: 'account.a'})
CALL {
  WITH [startNode] AS nodes, [] AS rels
  UNWIND nodes AS node
  FOREACH(ignoreMe IN [1] |
    MATCH (node)-[r]->(relatedNode)
    WHERE NOT relatedNode IN nodes
    SET nodes = nodes + relatedNode
    SET rels = rels + r
  )
}
RETURN DISTINCT nodes AS reachableNodes
```

ps- the data here is just a sample and in reality, the graph will have 100s of Account and Calculation nodes. The Relations between the nodes remain the same though. And no Calculation node will depend on a Account node with the same name + interest_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `APOC`. One of the advantages is that it easily gives you only the "end" nodes that you want:

```
MATCH(n:Account{name:'account.b'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
    relationshipFilter:"RESULTS_FROM>|DEPENDS_ON>",
    labelFilter: ">Account"
})
YIELD nodes
RETURN nodes
```

returns:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│nodes                                                           │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[(:Account {name: "account.y"}), (:Account {name: "account.c"})]│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**EDIT:**
`relationshipFilter` was changed from `>` to `RESULTS_FROM>|DEPENDS_ON>` according to @cybersam's remark

Comment: seems to get the job done. Will check apoc in details which I haven't done already :)

Comment: This query will follow all outgoing relationship types. You may need to be more specific if you will ever have other outgoing types than the ones mentioned in the question.

Comment: @cybersam, regarding your remark, this can be done easily by replacing the current `relationshipFilter` with: `RESULTS_FROM>|DEPENDS_ON>`

Answer (score 2):

You can be more specific about the pattern you're looking for by using a [quantified path pattern](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#quantified-path-patterns):

```
MATCH (:Account {name:'account.b'}) 
      (()-[:RESULTS_FROM]->(:Calculation)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:Account))+ (n)
RETURN collect(n)
```

Being more specific with patterns generally means faster.

Comment: makes sense. But if this is the only pattern in the entire graph, then will it make much difference -- apoc vs being more specific?

Comment: If there is also nothing else going on in the model, and the model doesn't change, then probably not. The other advantage is it's a more Cypher-ish syntax than the apoc functions, but that of course is more a question of taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#variable-length-relationships) to find all nodes that match the specified pattern (both `Calculation` and `Account` nodes):

```
MATCH (:Account {name: 'account.b'})-[:RESULTS_FROM|DEPENDS_ON*]->(n)
RETURN n
```

If you only want `Account` nodes, use this instead:

```
MATCH (:Account {name: 'account.b'})-[:RESULTS_FROM|DEPENDS_ON*]->(n:Account)
RETURN n
```

Comment: If I understand correctly this will return the "middle" nodes as well...

Comment: Yes. It finds all `n` nodes that fit the pattern.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to just get `Account` results, if that is your actual use case.