# Gremlin equivalent of an opencypher query

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a working opencypher query but due to some reason I have to go with gremlin.

[previous post with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053234/how-to-write-a-cypher-query-which-recursively-traverses-a-graph-in-neo4j-to-find)

### Query

```
MATCH (:Account {name: 'account.b'})-[:RESULTS_FROM|DEPENDS_ON*]->(n:Account)
RETURN n
```

I tried to write gremlin equivalent of it but it's not working as expected.

```
g.V().has('name', 'account.b').hasLabel('Account')
  .repeat(both('RESULTS_FROM', 'DEPENDS_ON').hasLabel('Account')).emit()
  .dedup()
```

How can I achieve the same behavior using gremlin.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. As the Cypher query is unbounded by number of hops, a `repeat...until` should work. I left the `dedup` in but in your Cypher query I do not see a `DISTINCT` so this may still give different answers. I changed `both` to `out`, as your Cypher query has a direction specifiied.

```java
g.V().has('name', 'account.b').
      hasLabel('Account').
      repeat(out('RESULTS_FROM', 'DEPENDS_ON')).
      until(hasLabel('Account')).
      dedup()
```

If there are cycles in the graph and you want to avoid visiting the same node twice for a given path, you can add a `simplePath()` after the `out()` as follows.

```java
g.V().has('name', 'account.b').
      hasLabel('Account').
      repeat(out('RESULTS_FROM', 'DEPENDS_ON').simplePath()).
      until(hasLabel('Account')).
      dedup()
```